# Centering Content of a Variable Length Pricing Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a basic pricing table.

The table can be of variable length: In some cases there is only 1 plan, in other cases there might be 5 plans.

**I can't figure out how to center all of the plans within a larger gray div.**

I am using twitter bootstrap.

Here is the jsfiddle. Notice how the plans are floating left instead of centering in the middle of the gray area

http://jsfiddle.net/vyjru/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of floating your pricing table items to the left, you can set them as `display:inline-block` and then simply set the `.pricing_sequence` container to `text-align:center;`

http://jsfiddle.net/vyjru/1/

**CSS**

```
.pricing_sequence{
    border:1px solid gainsboro;
    background-color:white;  
    text-align:center;
}

.pricing_sequence ol li{
    list-style:none;
    border-left:1px dashed gainsboro;    
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    vertical-align:top;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 160px;
    overflow: visible;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still want to keep the white to 160 each. in the link you gave, the white seems to stretch out. I want the two 160's (so 320px) centered in the overall gray area with the rest showing gray outside of the 320.

Comment: @jignesh i see what you mean, did not notice, you can pull off this effect by applying the property of `display:inline-block` to the `ol` as well. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/vyjru/2/

Comment: Andres, you rock! Thanks so much.

Comment: Hey Andres, one more question on this: http://jsfiddle.net/vyjru/3/  there is a vertical space between the two pricing plan boxes. You can see it on the right hand edge of the first box before the border begins for the right box. I can't find what's causing it. any ideas?

Comment: @jignesh that is due to the white space in your markup, but can be easily removed by adding `font-size:0` to your `ol` container and then simply resetting the `font-size` on the `li` themselves. Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyjru/4/